# ログイン時のcookie許可画面に英語が残っている

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

今日 (2023/2/16) ログインしたところ俗にいう cookie 許可画面に新しい選択肢 [Necessary cookies only] ボタンが追加されている様子。他が邦訳されているだけに残念感がすごいです。邦訳していただけると幸いです。訳文は [必須クッキーのみ] で十分かと。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

文字幅とバランスを考慮して、ひとまず「必要な Cookie のみ許可」としてみました。
「～許可する」だとレイアウトが崩れるので、左側も「すべての Cookie を許可」に調整しています。
(実際に反映されるまでは数日程度待ってみてください)

**ブラウザの開発者ツールで変更したプレビュー:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [必要な Cookie のみ許可] はプレビューのとおりなのですが [すべての Cookie を許可する] になっていますね・・・「る」だけ２行目に行ってる

Comment: 新しい翻訳自体は既に [追加済み](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/14460) なので、反映待ちの状態です。あまりにも時間がかかるようであれば、スタッフに調べてもらう事になると思います。

Comment: @774RR さん、@cubick さん、ありがとうございます！反映を確認いたしました‍♀️。